# float and clear doesn't work with span elements

Tags: html, css

1.The second span doesn't go below in spite of the clear property. Why?

2.The `display` property of the first is set to block when it got a float
property but the second doesn't go below (it is supposed to go below because the first span is block)

```css
.sp1,.sp2{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sp2{
clear: both;
}

.sp1{
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<span class="sp1">One</span>
<span class="sp2">Two</span>
```

Comment: Set the display to block, not inline-block